# Show that ${1,1-t,2-4t+t^2,6-18t+9t^2-t^3}$ is a basis in $P_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

How do i show that $\{1,1-t, 2-4t+t^2, 6-18t+9t^2-t^3\}$ is a basis in $P_3$ ?

Comment: I edited for the math formatting; I guess $P_3$ denotes the space of polynomials on $t$ with real coefficients and degree at most $3$?

Comment: yes Arnaud this is what i mean .. but i don't know how to format this correctly or how to edit it so i wont change it any further

Comment: Do you perhaps already have a basis for $P_3$? Express all elements of that basis in terms of the given functions.

Comment: @HansEngler I don't have anything else. this is the given problem to me.. I'm sorry could you explain more ?

Comment: Write an easy basis to work, after compute coordinates to work as same as in $\mathbb {R^4}$, the only information is in the coefficients.

Comment: @Abdullah3182 Simply put the math between dollar signs and it will appear with the good formatting. See also http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference (I think this was previously linked to your question but for some reason I can't see the comment anymore).

Comment: In the standard basis, it is a triangular system.

Comment: @Bernard how do i do it? do you know ? because i really im lost here

Comment: Write their coordinates in the basis $(1, t, t^2, t^3)$ as vector columns: you obtain an upper triangular matrix, with non-zero elements on the diagonal, hence the matrix has rank $4=\dim P_3$.

Comment: @Bernard I'm not sure if you get notified for comment in other places.. could you check the answer i just added?

Comment: I've made a explanation with a lot of details and words, since I believe it could be more useful to you. Truly I've made very few answers in this MSE. For your help too I tell to you that if there are an expression that you need to edit a new post, you can made click with the right bottom of your mouse, after select **Show Math As** and after select  **Text Commands** , then you can copy and modify in as plain text, to made a *copy and paste* in your edit, of your posts. Too you can type in Internet **MathJax Tutorial**. You are welcome to Math Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we assume that $\mathcal{P_3}=\mathcal{P_3}(\mathbb{R})$, **the vectorial space** (or the linear space) **of polynomials of degree least than $3$, with coefficients over real numbers.**

The following is a known fact

> **Fact.** The vectorial space $\mathcal{P_3}$ has dimension $4$ as  real vectorial space. And we can take and claim that $$\mathcal{B_{\mathcal{P_3}}}=\{1,t,t^2,t^3\},$$
>    is a basis, to work.

Then, in this point we can talk about vectors, no polynomials, what I say?

I say that to distinguish if two vectors $U=1$ and $V=6-18t+9t^2-t^3$, are the same your can to made a comparision componentwise to componentwise (the only information is in coefficients since as vectors the monomials and plus signs are accessories). The vectors $U$ and $V$ are distinct since have distinct componentwises (coefficients).

Now to distinguish if two vectors $U=1$ and $V=6-18t+9t^2-t^3$, are linearly independent, I should decide if these vectors could be proportionals in the sense that there exists $\lambda\neq 0$ such that $U=\lambda V$. I say that if such $\lambda$ exists then these vectors are proportionals, this is lineraly dependent vectors, thus these aren't linearly independent vectors. If in the process to find such $\lambda$ I obtain a *false statement*, then, by contradiction, I can claim that these vectors are linearly independent: When we assume that there is such real $\lambda$ then from a comparision in the vectorial equation, that it is assuming that these vectors are dependents 
$$1=\lambda\cdot (6-18t+9t^2-t^3),$$
produce this false statement, since from previous vectorial equation I can write these scalar equations when I made a comparision by componentwises (the olddest coefficients of our olddest polynomials)
$$1=\lambda\cdot 6, 0=\lambda\cdot (-18),  0=\lambda\cdot(9), \text{and }  0=\lambda\cdot(-1),$$
since by first scalar equation I deduce that $\lambda=\frac{1}{6}$, then for example I deduce the false statement $0=\frac{1}{6}\cdot(-18)=-3$. Thus I claim, by contradiction method, that is false that these vectors are dependents, thus are linearly independent vectors.

With previous, polynomials as abstract vectors are family.

**My solution** is only the observation that you can compute coordinates of each vector in the basis  $\mathcal{B_{\mathcal{P_3}}}$. For example the coordinates of your third vector $2-4t+t^2$ are $(2,-4,1,0)$, this is a **copy and paste** of the information encoded in your vector $2-4t+t^2$, when I translate coefficients in coordinates. **This method of copy and paste only can used when we work with a good basis as $\mathcal{B_{\mathcal{P_3}}}$.** The formalized method to compute coordinates is solve the vectorial equation

$$2-4t+t^2=w_1\cdot(1)+w_2\cdot(t)+w_3\cdot(t^2)+w_4\cdot(t^3),$$
by comparision you compute the same coordinates. When you made the same with all of your vectors, then you have computed all coordinates vectors and put these vectors as columns in a matrix, then since the determinant of such matrix isn't vanishes, this is $\neq 0$, you can claim that the vectors in columns, that are the coordinate vectors of your genuine vectors are $4$ linearly independent vectors in a real vectorial space of dimension $4$ (using the first **Fact**), thus your genuine set of vectors are a basis. For your test, the determinant of such matrix is $1\cdot(-1)\cdot 1\cdot(-1)=1\neq 0$

Comment: I'm sorry, I've update since there was a mistake in my first solution.

Comment: wow ... thanks for all that effort.. that was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDCSl.png)

am I going the right way here? What did i do wrong and what did i forget .. 
thank you all for your help.

Comment: @Bernard is this what you meant by writing their coordinates in the basis $(1,t,t^2,t^3)$ ?

Comment: It's OK. You just have to write the matrix with the coordinates as column vectors and explain why this matrix is invertble.

Comment: @Bernard so all i need is no write the columns in one matrix and get the inverse to show it is invertable  ?

Comment: You don't have to get the inverse matrix to show it is invertible.  It is enough to show its determinant is non-zero. Naturally, you may need to get the inverse for other questions…

Comment: @Bernard hey man could you help me out on how to put this ? i get it now .. columns are independent , and it spans $P_3$  so its a basis but i don't know how to phrase it .. i got to submit this tomorrow could you please help me with this?

Comment: Well you have a set of linearly independent vectors (<-> polynomials in $P_3$) which are linearly independent  and span $P_3$. Isn't it the definition of a basis of $P_3$?